# jQuery append does not work in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have the following code within a page

```
// some content .. <table>,<p>, etc ...
jQuery(function($) {
   $('[name="_wp_http_referer"]').attr('value', '/#/9/contact-us');
   // uncommenting this function call will generate error
   // appendIt();
   $.getScript('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha.js', function() {Recaptcha.create("6Lcc4OYSAAAAABTEzBumk7dNbnpKbpC3JhVdi2yU", "recaptcha_div");
   });
});
function appendIt(){
$('#recaptcha_div').children().append('<div for="cscf_recaptcha" class="help-inline"/>');
}
```

This is some kinda hack I did since the plugin does not work out of the box with my theme. However when I call the `appendIt` function I get the following error on my browser:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**

**UPDATED**

The content of "recaptcha_div".

```
<div id="recaptcha_div" class="controls">
    <noscript>&lt;iframe
        src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Lcc4OYSAAAAABTEzBumk7dNbnpKbpC3JhVdi2yU"
        height="300" width="500"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;br/&gt; &lt;textarea
        name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3"
        cols="40"&gt;&lt;/textarea&gt; &lt;input type="hidden"
        name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/&gt;</noscript>
    <div for="cscf_recaptcha" class="help-inline"></div>
</div>
```

What did I miss here ?

Comment: Where to you place this code?

Comment: Please post html also

Comment: can you share the `recaptcha_div` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by moving the code snippet from the *Edit Page* to an external JS file and include the JS file into the `functions.php`.

From what I understand script tag maybe inserted or called anywhere within the document but apparently this may not always be the case in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

is caused by illegal characters/symbol. Usually its a invisible characters at the end of line.

Copy paste the code snippets there into notepad, you'll see an extra "?" character at the end of the snippet code.

Comment: I tried what you have suggested but I am unable to find the extra character.